# How to cross product join in KQL

Tags: kql, azure-data-explorer

I am trying to create a resulting query but I am having difficulty. Currently I am trying to query for two values in one table, value A and value B. Each value has 5 different possible values. I want a result that shows the counts of each combination of values.

Value A 1, Value B 1 : count 3
Value A 1, Value B 2 : count 2
etc.

The issue is certain combinations don't exist and I want to include those combinations by showing a zero count. I'm not sure how to get those values to show up.

i get this:
V A 1, V B 1 : count 3
V A 1, V B 2 : count 4
V A 1, V B 4 : count 5

but i want this:

V A 1, V B 1 : count 3

V A 1, V B 2 : count 4
V A 1, V B 3 : count 0

V A 1, V B 4 : count 5

Thank you!

I tried to do a KQL cross product or a full outer join with exclusions, but neither seemed to work quite right.

Comment: Could you post an example dataset, ideally formatted as datatable? If you use Kusto Explorer then there is an option to copy a query result as datatable

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you were nearly there looking into the joins.  Possibly the one thing you may have missed is that like any query language KQL isn't good at showing you what *isn't* there.  So you have to generate all the possible values.

You'd need to generate a table for every possible value for ValueA and ValueB and then join that to data you have, that is your [`cross join`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/joinoperator?pivots=azuredataexplorer#cross-join).  If ValueA and ValueB are predictable I may computationally "brute force" it like the example below.

```
let T = datatable(ValueA:int, ValueB:int, count:int) [
1, 1, 3,
1, 2, 2,
2, 2, 4,
5, 9, 7
];
let ValueA = range ValueA from 1 to 10 step 1 //Generate all values for A
| extend JoinHere = 1; //Cross join
let ValueB = range ValueB from 1 to 10 step 1 //Generate all values for B
| extend JoinHere = 1; //Cross join
let AllValues = ValueA //Joined table
| join kind=leftouter (ValueB) on JoinHere;
AllValues
| join kind=leftouter (T) on ValueA, ValueB //Add in actual data and link on A and B
| extend ['count'] = coalesce(['count'], 0) //Where data exists show it, otherwise zero
| project ValueA, ValueB, ['count']
| order by ValueA asc, ValueB asc
```